# Extract XSD from top off XML file

Tags: xml, validation, parsing, xsd

I've been asked to make a program that validates XML against XSD. That's an easy part (and with lots of posts talking about it, I know).
My problem is this: XSD comes included in XML file, and I don't know how to extract it into a separate file for the parser to validate.
Attached image is an example of the kind of files I need to deal with, but this is a really simple one. We have XML files up to 220MB of size, so this needs to be efficient :D Thank you all in advance,
Samuel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfkKt.png

Comment: Witch language will you use to parse the files? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using C# to make a little app for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always struck me as pretty pointless to validate a file against a schema that comes with the file - if you don't trust the file to be valid, why should you trust it to contain a useful schema? But if that's what you want to do, then (a) some validation APIs may allow you to compile the schema directly from within its embedded location, and (b) if your chosen schema processor doesn't, then it can be extracted using a trivial XSLT or XQuery - for example the Saxon command

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -s:doc.xml -qs:"//xs:schema" -o:schema.xsd
```

For better performance, to avoid parsing the whole 220Mb, you could extract the schema using a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="3.0">

<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/xs:schema[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The `[1]` tells the processor that it can stop reading the input after it has processed the first xs:schema element.